# Rebooting Linux from PC with C#?

Tags: c#, windows, linux

Wondering if anyone has a simple solution to doing a reboot of a linux box from a C# windows app.  I can do the reboot using ssh, but really did not want to include the SSH lib files from [Tamir](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx)  Is there something else I could do besides bring in the full SSH lib for a simple reboot?

Here is how I do the reboot using Sharpssh from Tamir..

```
SshExec exec = new SshExec("192.168.1.1", "root", "password");
exec.RunCommand("/sbin/shutdown -r");
exec.Close();
```

Comment: Does the computer have SNMP running? Maybe you can reboot the machine through SNMP.

Comment: No SNMP, I think I am just going to use a different SSH lib to do this.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could send a Remote Procedure Call.

http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html

Comment: Tried this and it won't work for us.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Apache/PHP on the box?  If so, a horribly insecure way may be to setup a PHP page to initiate the reboot.  (You could attempt to add some security by requiring a login / obscure string supplied as a post variable, etc)  You can then just [use a WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) to call the page in question to initiate the reboot.

Please don't ask me about the security specifics of allowing a PHP page to call out to a system command with the required permissions - it has been far too long since I worked on Linux / PHP.

Comment: excellent idea, but would not work for us as I dont have access to the box to put the script on it.